# Populando select com dados enviado do controller e tentando salvar no BD

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Estou mandando para o form uma array para popular o select assim,

controller que manda para a view:

```
const novaForm = async ({ Maquina }, req, res) => {
const maquina = await Maquina.find({status: 'livre'})
res.render('operacoes/nova', { maquina })
}
```

View:

```
<select name="maquina" class="custom-select" id="maquina">
<option selected>máquina</option>
<% maquina.forEach( maq => { %>
<option value="<%= maq.nome %>"><%= maq.nome %></option>
<% }) %>
</select>
```

Controller que salva:

```
const novaProcess = async ({ Operacao }, req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)
const operacao = new Operacao(req.body)
try{
    await operacao.save() 
    res.redirect('/operacoes')
} catch (e) {
    res.render('operacoes/nova', {errors: Object.keys(e.errors)})
 }
}
```

Mas quando eu mando salvar me é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
45    <select name="maquina" class="custom-select" id="maquina">
46                           <option selected>máquina</option>
47                           <% maquina.forEach( maq => { %>
48                           <option value="<%= maq.nome %>"><%= maq.nome %></option>
49|                           <% }) %>
50|                         </select>

maquina is not defined
```

Ele popula certinho o select, sem erro nenhum, o erro ocorre apenas ao mandar salvar.

Comment: Coloca um console.log da variável operacao após ela pegar os dados do req.body e me fala aqui como ela retorna

Comment: Olha o retorno da operacao amigo...
{ _id: 5c9bebd72dc5bb196cb7027d,
  maquina: '5c9793558a7fae2e6c6dbb0b' }